# getApliClient.isConnected() returns false while connecting to Leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-services

I already posted a question regarding this. But I received no help with this question. Can anyone help me out with this. w

```
if(getApiClient().isConnected() && overv>0){
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),getString(R.string.leaderboard_game_score),overv);
        }
```

This return false to me. Were Overv is an Integer which is my overall score stored in database. I am calling this is in oncreate method of the MainActivity. I have published this game. Kindly help with this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You must call connect on the API Client and then wait for the success callback. something like this.

In OnCreate

```
getApiClient().connect();
```

Then your class should implement the connection callbacks. GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),getString(R.string.leaderboard_game_score),overv);
}
```

Look at the docs/samples. They give very good examples on how to properly implement this.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Comment: Sorry for the delay got busy with the work.. And I tried all this. FYI I have developed applications using Google Apis like drive, map, google+ and GCM. So I am having few knowledge about this stuff. Still I couldn't find where I went wrong. :) Thank you